# bash: split output of command by columns without specific delimiter

Tags: macos, bash

I'm try to extract the contents of a given column, but spaces have been used to format the columns so I don't have a specific delimiter to work with.

The data I'm working with is the result of the following OS X command:

```
diskutil list | grep 'Apple'
```

Example output:

```
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh SSD           511.8 GB   disk0s2
   2:                  Apple_HFS External                79.7 GB    disk1s2
```

The column I want to extract is the disk name, i.e. "Macintosh SSD" and "External"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `diskutil list -plist` and parse the property list instead.  The human-readable output is not meant to be machine readable, and might look different than you expect (column boundaries could move to accommodate long outputs or a wide terminal window, etc).

Comment: Like @ "The human-readable output is not meant to be machine readable"

Comment: Thank you. It wasn't the answer I was hoping for, but it's spot on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to print the words from the 3rd to the Nth-3. If so, the following awk will do:

```
gawk '{disk=""; for (i = 3; i <= NF-3; i++){disk=disk $i " "};print disk}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `tr -s ' '` to collapse (squeeze) spaces:

```
diskutil list | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 3 | grep Apple
```

Or just regex:

```
diskutil list | sed -En 's/^[ 0-9]+: +(Apple[^ ]+).+/\1/p'
```